# How can I get the OOB score of each tree in random forest?(scikit-learn)

Tags: python, random-forest

It seems that the RandomForestClassifier model in scikit-learn only provides the overall out-of-bag (OOB) score for the entire forest.I wanna get the obb score of each tree.Is there any ideas?Thanks!

I wanna get the obb score of each tree in the whole forest.

Answer (score 0):

Using the estimators_ attribute, you first extract individual trees in a scikit-learn RandomForestClassifier in order to get the Out-Of-Bag (OOB) score for each tree. Next, determine the OOB samples for each tree and determine the correctness of the tree based on these samples. Lastly, repeat this method iteratively through each tree, storing each tree's unique OOB scores for analysis.

Comment: if you provide the code , I will be able to suggest changes for it easily.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code snippet in your code after fitting data to classifier & generating overall OOB score:

```
# Get the OOB score for each individual tree
individual_tree_oob_scores = []

for tree in rf_classifier.estimators_:
    # Find the indices of out-of-bag samples for each tree
    oob_indices = set(tree.apply(X_train)[:, 0])

    # Filter out-of-bag samples
    X_oob, y_oob = X_train[list(oob_indices)], y_train[list(oob_indices)]

    # Make predictions on out-of-bag samples
    y_pred_oob = tree.predict(X_oob)   

    # Calculate the OOB score for the tree
    tree_oob_score = accuracy_score(y_oob, y_pred_oob)

    # Store the OOB score for the tree
    individual_tree_oob_scores.append(tree_oob_score)

# Print the OOB score for each individual tree
for i, score in enumerate(individual_tree_oob_scores):
     print(f"Tree {i + 1} OOB Score: {score:.4f}")
```

Comment: Actually, the answer from GPT is wrong.You can not get the real oob_indices.And the return of method--tree.apply() is the index of the leaf that each sample is predicted as.